# mysql find duplications

Tags: mysql

this is the table

```
fid  uid  time
12   34   1
1    34   2
15   34   5
1    33   10
12   33   10
1    33   12
13   33   15
16   34   123
22   32   453
1    32   456
1    33   457
1    32   460
```

now I want to count the number of each `uid` where `time is >9` and `fid=1`
like this

```
uid     number of duplications
33      3
32      2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT uid, COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE fid=1 AND `time` > 9 GROUP BY uid
```